# How to extract the content of FROM clause in a Oracle view

Tags: sql, database, oracle, view

I want to get the sources used in an Oracle view.

Eg -

```
SELECT a.name, b.name, c.age FROM customer_tab a, employee_tab b, employee_detail_tab c
```

Given that I have the above view deployed in the Oracle DB, is there a way to extract the objects in the FROM clause?

Answer (score 4):

You can query [DBA_DEPENDENCIES](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/DBA_DEPENDENCIES.html) which

> describes all dependencies between objects in the database. This view
> does not display the SCHEMAID column.

or [ALL_DEPENDENCIES](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/ALL_DEPENDENCIES.html#GUID-F9EA7DFB-5471-4B07-BDEF-FDE5DF57D1F4) which

> describes dependencies between procedures, packages, functions,
> package bodies, and triggers accessible to the current user, including
> dependencies on views created without any database links. This view
> does not display the SCHEMAID column.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the explain plan. Just do:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR <your query>;
```

and then you can do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT object_name
  FROM plan_table
 WHERE object_name IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: It will return all the objects in underlying views (and indexes, temp tables of materialized `with` etc), not just objects referenced in a query. And if the query is rewritten to access a materialized view, then it will completely hide original objects

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the code below to get the dependences upto 6 levels deep...

```sql
--  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--  Shows objects that given object depends on
--          --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--          MOTE :
--              The code uses recursions - so it is highly advisable to use it just for one object at a time to prevent infinite recursions 
--              Source is system table DBA_DEPENDENCIES to which you'd need to have access to
--              If not use ALL_DEPENDENCIES instead
--          --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--  Parameters are of type VarChar2 (They Are Not Case Sensitive) and should be provided within single quates:
--      like    -   OwnerName -> 'scott'        ObjectName -> 'my_view'     ObjectType -> 'VIEW'
--
--  Resulting fotmat:   --->    [Object_Type] "ObjectName" (owner.OwnerName)    <---
--  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WITH
    obj AS
        (   Select &OwnerName "OWNED_BY", &ObjectName "OBJ_NAME", &ObjectType "OBJ_TYPE" From Dual  ), 
--  ---------------------------------------
    obj_deps_1 AS
        (   Select
                o.OBJ_NAME "OBJ_NAME",
                o.OBJ_TYPE "OBJ_TYPE",
                o.OWNED_BY "OBJ_OWNED_BY",
                --
                CASE WHEN d.REFERENCED_OWNER IN('SYS', 'PUBLIC') THEN Null ELSE d.REFERENCED_NAME END "REF_OBJ_NAME_1",
                CASE WHEN d.REFERENCED_OWNER IN('SYS', 'PUBLIC') THEN Null ELSE d.REFERENCED_TYPE END "REF_OBJ_TYPE_1",
                CASE WHEN d.REFERENCED_OWNER IN('SYS', 'PUBLIC') THEN Null ELSE d.REFERENCED_OWNER END "REF_OBJ_OWNED_BY_1"
                --
            From 
                obj o 
            Inner Join
                ALL_DEPENDENCIES d ON(d.OWNER = Upper(o.OWNED_BY) And d.NAME = Upper(o.OBJ_NAME) And d.TYPE = Upper(o.OBJ_TYPE))
        ),
    obj_deps_6 AS
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT
                o.OBJ_NAME "OBJ_NAME",
                o.OBJ_TYPE "OBJ_TYPE",
                o.OBJ_OWNED_BY "OBJ_OWNED_BY",
                --
                o.REF_OBJ_NAME_1 "REF_OBJ_NAME_1",
                o.REF_OBJ_TYPE_1 "REF_OBJ_TYPE_1",
                o.REF_OBJ_OWNED_BY_1 "REF_OBJ_OWNED_BY_1",
                --
                CASE WHEN d2.REFERENCED_OWNER IN('SYS', 'PUBLIC') THEN Null ELSE d2.REFERENCED_NAME END "REF_OBJ_NAME_2",
                CASE WHEN d2.REFERENCED_OWNER IN('SYS', 'PUBLIC') THEN Null ELSE d2.REFERENCED_TYPE END "REF_OBJ_TYPE_2",
                CASE WHEN d2.REFERENCED_OWNER IN('SYS', 'PUBLIC') THEN Null ELSE d2.REFERENCED_OWNER END "REF_OBJ_OWNED_BY_2",
                --
                CASE WHEN d3.REFERENCED_OWNER IN('SYS', 'PUBLIC') THEN Null ELSE d3.REFERENCED_NAME END "REF_OBJ_NAME_3",
                CASE WHEN d3.REFERENCED_OWNER IN('SYS', 'PUBLIC') THEN Null ELSE d3.REFERENCED_TYPE END "REF_OBJ_TYPE_3",
                CASE WHEN d3.REFERENCED_OWNER IN('SYS', 'PUBLIC') THEN Null ELSE d3.REFERENCED_OWNER END "REF_OBJ_OWNED_BY_3",
                --
                CASE WHEN d4.REFERENCED_OWNER IN('SYS', 'PUBLIC') THEN Null ELSE d4.REFERENCED_NAME END "REF_OBJ_NAME_4",
                CASE WHEN d4.REFERENCED_OWNER IN('SYS', 'PUBLIC') THEN Null ELSE d4.REFERENCED_TYPE END "REF_OBJ_TYPE_4",
                CASE WHEN d4.REFERENCED_OWNER IN('SYS', 'PUBLIC') THEN Null ELSE d4.REFERENCED_OWNER END "REF_OBJ_OWNED_BY_4",
                --
                CASE WHEN d5.REFERENCED_OWNER IN('SYS', 'PUBLIC') THEN Null ELSE d5.REFERENCED_NAME END "REF_OBJ_NAME_5",
                CASE WHEN d5.REFERENCED_OWNER IN('SYS', 'PUBLIC') THEN Null ELSE d5.REFERENCED_TYPE END "REF_OBJ_TYPE_5",
                CASE WHEN d5.REFERENCED_OWNER IN('SYS', 'PUBLIC') THEN Null ELSE d5.REFERENCED_OWNER END "REF_OBJ_OWNED_BY_5",
                --
                CASE WHEN d6.REFERENCED_OWNER IN('SYS', 'PUBLIC') THEN Null ELSE d6.REFERENCED_NAME END "REF_OBJ_NAME_6",
                CASE WHEN d6.REFERENCED_OWNER IN('SYS', 'PUBLIC') THEN Null ELSE d6.REFERENCED_TYPE END "REF_OBJ_TYPE_6",
                CASE WHEN d6.REFERENCED_OWNER IN('SYS', 'PUBLIC') THEN Null ELSE d6.REFERENCED_OWNER END "REF_OBJ_OWNED_BY_6"
            FROM
                obj_deps_1 o
            LEFT JOIN
                ALL_DEPENDENCIES d2 ON(d2.NAME = Nvl(o.REF_OBJ_NAME_1, 'no_object') And d2.TYPE = Nvl(o.REF_OBJ_TYPE_1, 'no_type'))
            LEFT JOIN
                ALL_DEPENDENCIES d3 ON(d3.NAME = Nvl(d2.REFERENCED_NAME, 'no_object') And d3.TYPE = Nvl(d2.REFERENCED_TYPE, 'no_type'))
            LEFT JOIN
                ALL_DEPENDENCIES d4 ON(d4.NAME = Nvl(d3.REFERENCED_NAME, 'no_object') And d4.TYPE = Nvl(d3.REFERENCED_TYPE, 'no_type'))
            LEFT JOIN
                ALL_DEPENDENCIES d5 ON(d5.NAME = Nvl(d4.REFERENCED_NAME, 'no_object') And d5.TYPE = Nvl(d4.REFERENCED_TYPE, 'no_type'))
            LEFT JOIN
                ALL_DEPENDENCIES d6 ON(d6.NAME = Nvl(d5.REFERENCED_NAME, 'no_object') And d6.TYPE = Nvl(d5.REFERENCED_TYPE, 'no_type'))
        )
SELECT 
    REPLACE('[' || OBJ_TYPE || '] "' || OBJ_NAME || '" (owner.' || OBJ_OWNED_BY || ')', '[] "" (owner.)', 'None') "OBJECT",
    REPLACE('[' || REF_OBJ_TYPE_1 || '] "' || REF_OBJ_NAME_1 || '" (owner.' || REF_OBJ_OWNED_BY_1 || ')', '[] "" (owner.)', 'None') "DEPENDENCY_1",
    REPLACE('[' || REF_OBJ_TYPE_2 || '] "' || REF_OBJ_NAME_2 || '" (owner.' || REF_OBJ_OWNED_BY_2 || ')', '[] "" (owner.)', 'None') "DEPENDENCY_2",
    REPLACE('[' || REF_OBJ_TYPE_3 || '] "' || REF_OBJ_NAME_3 || '" (owner.' || REF_OBJ_OWNED_BY_3 || ')', '[] "" (owner.)', 'None') "DEPENDENCY_3",
    REPLACE('[' || REF_OBJ_TYPE_4 || '] "' || REF_OBJ_NAME_4 || '" (owner.' || REF_OBJ_OWNED_BY_4 || ')', '[] "" (owner.)', 'None') "DEPENDENCY_4",
    REPLACE('[' || REF_OBJ_TYPE_5 || '] "' || REF_OBJ_NAME_5 || '" (owner.' || REF_OBJ_OWNED_BY_5 || ')', '[] "" (owner.)', 'None') "DEPENDENCY_5",
    REPLACE('[' || REF_OBJ_TYPE_6 || '] "' || REF_OBJ_NAME_6 || '" (owner.' || REF_OBJ_OWNED_BY_6 || ')', '[] "" (owner.)', 'None') "DEPENDENCY_6"
FROM
    obj_deps_6
ORDER BY
    OBJ_NAME, OBJ_TYPE,
    REF_OBJ_NAME_1, REF_OBJ_TYPE_1,
    REF_OBJ_NAME_2, REF_OBJ_TYPE_2,
    REF_OBJ_NAME_3, REF_OBJ_TYPE_3,
    REF_OBJ_NAME_4, REF_OBJ_TYPE_4,
    REF_OBJ_NAME_5, REF_OBJ_TYPE_5
```

running it you'll be asked for three parameters (you can put your own)...

```sql
Enter Value For OwnerName:  'user_1'
Enter Value For ObjectName: 'some_view_to_check'
Enter Value For ObjectType: 'view'

R e s u l t :
OBJECT                                      DEPENDENCY_1                            DEPENDENCY_2                    DEPENDENCY_3        DEPENDENCY_4        DEPENDENCY_5        DEPENDENCY_6
------------------------------------------  --------------------------------------- ------------------------------- ------------------- ------------------- ------------------- ---------------------
[view] "some_view_to_check" (owner.user_1)  [VIEW] "SOME_VIEW_1"  (owner.USER_1)    [TABLE] "TABLE2" (owner.USER_1) None                None                None                None
[view] "some_view_to_check" (owner.user_1)  [VIEW] "SOME_VIEW_1"  (owner.USER_1)    [TABLE] "TABLE3" (owner.USER_1) None                None                None                None
[view] "some_view_to_check" (owner.user_1)  [TABLE] "SOME_TABLE1" (owner.USER_1)    None                            None                None                None                None
```

the result says that the view "some_view_to_check" uses another view "SOME_VIEW_1" and a table "SOME_TABLE1" (this is Dependency_1) ... Furthermore, the view "SOME_VIEW_1" uses two tables: TABLE2 and TABLE3 (Dependency_2)